# Documentation score and tag badges

Tags: support, documentation, tag-badges

I was wondering whether upvotes on documentation topics and examples had any influence on the obtention of bronze, silver and gold badges for the tag.

In the description of the gold tag badge, it is written

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge

If I get 100 upvotes on the documentation for one tag, does it mean I only need 900 upvotes on answers?

I guess the formulation so far excludes this possibility but is it planned that documentation scores will influence the tag badges?

Comment: Can you please describe a little bit more? I could not get your point.

Comment: Most of the content in docs will have many authors, so it shouldn't count toward tag scores/badges...

Comment: @DanielNugent Most of the content in docs will have many authors, so it shouldn't give rep, but it still does ...

Comment: It would make sense to me if proven ability to write documentation contributed to one's progress towards privileges associated with tag badges: bypassing documentation change review and even the Q&A gold badge dupe hammer. Especially as documentation is structured around tags.

Answer (score 1):

No, the tag badges don't count the score of the documentation examples you've created / contributed to.